# Parsing process start time from linux "ps" command output in c#

Tags: c#, linux, parsing, date, datetime

How can I parse the start time output of the ps command? It can parse if it's in the form, like `06:38PM`, but when it looks like `Tue01PM` it somehow can't. I also tried to add cultureinfo, like `Convert.ToDateTime(result[8], CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))`, and with `ParseExact` like `DateTime.ParseExact(result[8], "dddhhhh", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))`.

Comment: The real question is: How are you getting such wildly different representations? That second one I have never seen and I work with Linux systems constantly. 

What is your error anyways? Without that no one can help you

Comment: What is the supposed output of Tue01PM, anyway? For me it sounds very non-deterministic as depending on the current date?

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno The problem is, that I have Visual Studio in a different language (hungarian), hence the error message is also hungarian. Can I get the english message somehow? (It says something like the character string cannot be interpreted as a valid DateTime value). Also it's a bit complicated situation, cause it's coming from ios with ssh. But I don't think it's matter in this case, I just asked, if there's a way to parse that string as DateTime.

Comment: @Georg `06:38PM` depends on the current date as well, but it's parsable.  I think the expected outcome would be the previous tuesday 01 pm. Ca a string be parsed like that?

Comment: I don't know anything about hungarian letter, but if they aren't ASCII then you will have issues. If you're trying to parse the date output from a hungarian Linux command line I have a feeling you're going about this entirely wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ps` command can be asked to present specific data, and in some cases in specific formats, which can make it easier to parse the results. You request specific data with the `-o` command line option, whose argument is a comma-separated list of items in the form: `item=HEADER`. `HEADER` is the column header to use; leaving it out means that no header will be printed for that column (but if you also leave out the `=`, you'll get a default header).

There are at least two common items for start time: `start` and `lstart`. These give you the standard and long versions of the time, respectively:

```
$ ps -ostart= 2875
11:28:13
$ ps -olstart= 2875
Wed Mar 18 11:28:13 2015
```

On Linux, `ps` gets its information from the "file" `/proc/pid/stat`, which is a single line containing space-separated fields (see `man 5 proc`). The start time is the 22nd item in the list; it is an integer, which represents the number of clock ticks since the system was booted. In bash, you can convert this to something more usable with a bit of work:

```
start_time() {
  local now running ticks uptime
  now=$(date +%s)            # time in seconds since epoch
  running=$(cut -d' ' -f22 /proc/$1/stat)
                             # start time of process in ticks since boot
  ticks=$(getconf CLK_TCK)   # ticks per second (usually 100)
  uptime=($(</proc/uptime))  # seconds since boot and idle time
  bc <<<"$now-${uptime[0]}+$running/$ticks"
}

$ date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" -d@$(start_time 2875)
2015-03-18 11:28:12
```

Comment: Tanks for the stat file idea, but as I mentioned, I'm on iOs, and I have no idea how to find it there (there's no proc folder). However that `-olstart` worked, and I could succesfully parse the date from the long format.

Comment: @Geiszla: cool. I know almost nothing about iOS (and I didn't see it mentioned in your question anywhere). You gave your question a `linux` tag, which is why I provided a linux answer.

Comment: Yeah, that was my answer too :) Just not with an example

Answer (score 0):

In linux, you can [override the system date format](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_date.htm) and give it whatever you'd like. Then you can be sure of the output. That is what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

Gives the starting time in epoc of pid / process $MYPID

```
MYPID=$PPID
STARTING_EPOC_OF_MYPID=$(date +%s -d "$(ps -olstart= ${MYPID})")
echo $STARTING_EPOC_OF_MYPID
```

I'm not quite sure, if this differs from above.